# Show that $\mu : \mathcal P(\mathbb N) \to [0, \infty ]$ is a measure.

Tags: measure-theory

> I have the following question:
>
> [image]

I am trying to show that $\mu : \mathcal P(\mathbb N) \to [0, \infty ]$ is a measure.

I know that, in order to do so, I need to show that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive, that is, whenever $\{A_n\}$ is a disjoint sequence of $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ satisfying $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \in P(\mathbb N)$, then $\mu\left( \displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu \left( \displaystyle A_n \right)$.

How do I show this?

Comment: @math635 - So far I only have that $A = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} a_n$ and consequently $\mu(A) = \mu (\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} a_n) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} a_n$. But I don't know if that is correct or how to proceed from there.

Comment: I think you messed up your $a_i$ and your $A_i$'s? Why do we have $A = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} a_n$??

Comment: @math635 I think you are correct. I am wrong in saying that $A = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N } a_n$. But I have no idea what to do then :(

Comment: you should try to make yourself an intuitive idea of what is a measure. at first, you can think to $\mu(A)$ as $P(X \in A)$ (which is always $\ge 0$) where $X$ is some random variable (continuous or discrete) on $\mathbb{R}$, or to integrals : $\int_{A \cup B} d\mu =\int_{A} d\mu + \int_{B} d\mu$ with the restriction $\int_{A} d\mu \ge 0$

Comment: and on the last line; you should have written that $A = \bigcup_nA_n \implies \mu(A) =\mu(\bigcup_n A_n) = \sum_n \mu(A_n)$

Comment: @user1952009 I just uploaded a picture of the actual question reference. I might have made a mistake in typing my question incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $(A_j)$ are disjoint subsets of $\mathbb N$. Then
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_jA_j\right)=\sum_{n\in\bigcup_jA_j}a_n=\sum_j\sum_{n\in A_j}a_n=\sum_j\mu(A_j)$$
where the summation order is justified since $A_j$ are disjoint and $a_n\ge0$.